# Angular observable and subscription

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

i have one observable function in my service which i have subscribe but i am getting **[object Object]** instead of token value

## service code:

```
get bearerToken(): Observable<string | null> {
  return this.store.select(AuthStatusState.getToken).pipe(
       map((token) => {
         if (token) {
           return token;
         } else {
           return null;
         }
       }),
       take(1)
     );
   }
```

## code to which i have subscribed.

```
const authToken = this.authService.bearerToken.subscribe();
console.log(authToken);
```

i want token to be saved in const instead of object

Comment: You're logging the subscription, not the value returned by the subscription. Try `this.authService.bearerToken.subscribe(res => console.log(res));`.

Comment: i did this and  got following 

console.log(authToken); // this return token value

where-as below  returns: Rabbit [object Object] 


if (authToken) {
console.log('Rabbit' + authToken);
}

Comment: If you want a token you have to put method receiving this token inside subscribe because you are saving reference to the observer instead of token. Here have a read: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/angular/angular-subscribe/

Comment: i was able to solve using this approach: this.myService.myBehaviorSubject.subscribe(data => this.myData = data)

Answer (score 0):

Like this `authToken` is a subscription.

```js
const authToken = this.authService.bearerToken.subscribe();
```

Like this `authToken` will be the value emitted by `bearerToken`.

```js
let authToken;
this.authService.bearerToken.subscribe( data => authToken = data);
console.log(authToken);
```

Comment: console.log here still could not print the authToken value, move it the subscribe().